# What is a Java alternative for TS return type union?

Tags: java, generics

Trying to convert this TS code to Java
https://github.com/supermacro/neverthrow/blob/cab111f3378fd5bd0810b543d481185796333474/src/result.ts

I have no idea how can I do the following:

given

```
export class Ok<T, E> implements IResult<T, E> {
```

it is possible to return union type which is not present in generic

```
andThen<U, F>(f: (t: T) => Result<U, F>): Result<U, E | F>
```

specifically, it returns not only `E` which satisfies generic bounds, but also `F` which is completely unrelated.

Doing so in Java will result in

```
record Err<T, E>(E err) implements Result<T, E> {
....
        public <newT, newE> Result<newT, newE> andThen(Function<T, Result<newT, newE>> f) {
            return new Err<>(err);
        }
```

results in

```
Required type: Result<newT,newE>
Provided: Err<Object,E>
no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that E conforms to newE inference variable E has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: newE lower bounds: E
```

Using wildcards doesn't help here because later on a class `X` will not satisfy `? extends Y` capture bound, even though `X` extends `Y`.

Please give any suggestions on this? I suppose it's not possible to do the same in Java as TS allows.

Comment: No there is no union types. How about writing an `Either<A, B>` record, so `andThen` can return `Result<newT, Either<E, newE>>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no union type constraints for generics, but you can just use a wildcard:

```
sealed interface Result<T, E> {
    <U, F> Result<U, ?> andThen(Function<T, Result<U, F>> f);
}

record Ok<T, E>(T value) implements Result<T, E> {
    @Override
    public <U, F> Result<U, F> andThen(Function<T, Result<U, F>> f) {
        return f.apply(value);
    }
}

record Err<T, E>(E err) implements Result<T, E> {
    @Override
    public <U, F> Result<U, E> andThen(Function<T, Result<U, F>> f) {
        return new Err<>(err);
    }
}
```

Obviously you're ceding some type safety as you're losing the ability to say that the wildcard type is either `E` or `F`, but this is as close as you can easily get in Java (without recourse to creating your own union type wrapper).